# Angular 17 can not use ngOninit()

Tags: angular

When I try to use ngOninit() i got this error:

```
ERROR HttpErrorResponse {
  headers: _HttpHeaders {
    normalizedNames: Map(0) {},
    lazyUpdate: null,
    headers: Map(0) {}
  },
  status: 0,
  statusText: 'Unknown Error',
  url: 'https://localhost:44387/api/project-service/domain/domains?skip=1&maxResultCount=10',
  ok: false,
  name: 'HttpErrorResponse',
  message: 'Http failure response for https://localhost:44387/api/project-service/domain/domains?skip=1&maxResultCount=10: 0 undefined',
  error: TypeError: fetch failed
      at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11576:11)
      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
    cause: Error: self-signed certificate
        at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (node:_tls_wrap:1550:34)
        at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (d:/Home/Projectvil/src_projectvil-frontend/projectvil/node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone-node.js:402:31)
        at AsyncStackTaggingZoneSpec.onInvokeTask (d:/Home/Projectvil/src_projectvil-frontend/projectvil/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:14509:28)
        at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (d:/Home/Projectvil/src_projectvil-frontend/projectvil/node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone-node.js:401:60)
        at Object.onInvokeTask (d:/Home/Projectvil/src_projectvil-frontend/projectvil/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:14819:33)
        at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (d:/Home/Projectvil/src_projectvil-frontend/projectvil/node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone-node.js:401:60)
        at _Zone.runTask (d:/Home/Projectvil/src_projectvil-frontend/projectvil/node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone-node.js:173:47)
        at invokeTask (d:/Home/Projectvil/src_projectvil-frontend/projectvil/node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone-node.js:483:34)
        at TLSSocket.ZoneTask.invoke (d:/Home/Projectvil/src_projectvil-frontend/projectvil/node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone-node.js:472:48)
        at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:514:28) {
      code: 'DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT'
    }
  }
}
```

this my implementation

```
ngOnInit() {
    const request: IPagedAndSortiedAndFilteredRequestInput = {
      filter: '',
      sort: '',
      skip: 1,
      maxResultCount: 10
    };

    this.domainService.get(request)
      .subscribe({
        next: (data: IPageResultDto<IDomainDto>) => {
          this.domains = data.items
        }
      });
  }
```

and here the service

> ```
> get(data: IDomainInput) : Observable<IPageResultDto<IDomainDto>> {
>     const params = this.pageSettingsService.createParams(data);
>     const url = `${this.gateway}/${Project_Service}/${this.entity}/domains`;
>
>     return this.http.get<IPageResultDto<IDomainDto>>(url, { params })
>       .pipe(
>         map((response: IPageResultDto<IDomainDto>) => response)
>       );
>   }
> ```

the same if I try to use this login into construcrot

But if I use the same logic but not in ngOninit it works correct.
Do you have any ideas?
Thanks in advance

Comment: This almost certainly has nothing to do with `ngOnInit`. It's an error caused by the HTTP call: `cause: Error: self-signed certificate`. If it works in other cases, you're likely changing something else in those cases.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Do you mean certificate on backend side?

Answer (score 0):

I see the next code in your error message: `DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT`. This error typically occurs when the backend server is using a self-signed SSL certificate, and the client application (your Angular application) is rejecting it due to security concerns. I think [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580508/getting-chrome-to-accept-self-signed-localhost-certificate) will help you.